# Python: open either zipped or unzipped file using "with"

Tags: python, with-statement

I'm looking for a solution to open a file using "with". Hoever, I would like to check if the file is either gzipped or not and then either use gzip.open or just open something like:

```
if f.endswith(".gz"):
    with gzip.open() as f:
else:
    with open() as f:
for line in f:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Move the ```for``` statement into a function and pass ```f``` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to creating another context manager, you can simply choose the function within your `with` statement:

```
with (gzip.open if filename.endswith(".gz") else open)(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

(While being aware that ending with `.gz` does not necessarily make a file a gzip file).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this is by making your own context manager that does it for you.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def open_file(filename):
    if filename.endswith(".gz"):
        with gzip.open(filename) as f:
            yield f
    else:
        with open(filename) as f:
            yield f
```

Then you can just open files using this instead.

```
with open_file("filename") as f:
    # f will be either the result of `gzip.open` or `open`, depending on its filename.
    for line in f:
        pass
```

This gives you the ability to keep the advantages of using a `with` clause, whilst giving you the flexibility to choose which function to call.

Comment: That looks great. For simplicity I will go with donkopotamus' solution but I like this one a lot, too.

Comment: Fair enough. Both solutions have pros and cons - I'd probably recommend his in the case of there being only one instance of the call, and mine if it's used twice or more in the code base. Mine is also more expandable. Either way, don't forget to accept the answer you choose :)

Comment: Done :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I like Shadow's answer, and the updated version works for me. Here is a slightly simplified version that should also work:

```
def open_smart(filename, mode = "r"):
    if filename.endswith(".gz"):
        return(gzip.open(filename, mode))
    else:
        return(open(filename, mode))
```

Comment: If you're opening a gz file - I highly down that you want to open it in text mode. Maybe check my answer again - cause I did notice I forgot to add the contextmanager decorator to the function.

Comment: Thx for the update, I tried your solution and it works now. But mine works as well, the reading in text mode doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: You will run into problems on windows in particular - as `\n` gets 'helpfully' replaced with `\r\n` and if you happen to have that character somewhere in the 7z file, it'll cause corruption. Though on linux, and with good luck it won't be an issue.

Comment: It's worth also noting that this won't automatically close the file like mine does. EDIT: Actually, calling this in the with statement would do the trick. Might be worth showing an example usage just so people don't use this incorrectly :)